# Using TMB to take a weighted mean over posteriors

Tags: tmb

First off, I'm brand new to TMB, and fairly new to working with SPDE models as well.

I would like to combine posteriors from several SPDE models using a weighted mean (weights reflecting the variance in each posterior). Is this possible to do in TMB?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, Wave! Can I ask which package are you referring to?

Comment: Sorry, you can adapt the function for your model from here: https://github.com/fishfollower/SAM/blob/master/stockassessment/R/tables.R